# Bottom Navigation Bar with show/hide snap animation dependent upon speed of user scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I attach my code for a simple bottom nav bar, where it shows or hides as the user scrolls up and down. However I would like to change the behaviour of the bar, so that it has more of a spring/snap effect, dependent on the speed and direction the user is scrolling, and which avoids it being stuck half on/off. The video below gives an idea of the effect I am after:

https://youtube.com/shorts/r6e8VEhz2hA

Here is my existing code, ready to run:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<BottomNavBarItemData> screens = [];
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final List<String> items = List<String>.generate(30, (i) => 'Item $i');

  // navigation bar show/hide settings
  final int _duration = 600; // speed the bar hides
  int _timeScrolled = 0;
  bool _scrollingUp = false;
  final int _scrollSensitivity = 300; // how long we pause before applying the animation when user scrolls

  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: _duration),
    vsync: this,
  );
  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.easeInBack,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _setupScreens();
    _controller.forward();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        // user scrolling up so initiate hiding of nav bar
        if (_scrollingUp) {
          // make scrolling less sensitive, user has to scroll with intent before bar hides
          if (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - _timeScrolled > _scrollSensitivity) {
            doAnimatorReverse();
          }
        } else {
          _scrollingUp = true;
          _timeScrolled = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        }
      }
      if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
        _scrollingUp = false;
        doAnimatorForward();
      }
      if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        bool isTop = _scrollController.position.pixels == 0;
        if (!isTop) {
          doAnimatorForward();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  doAnimatorForward() {
    if (_controller.isAnimating) return;
    _controller.forward();
  }

  doAnimatorReverse() {
    if (_controller.isAnimating) return;
    _controller.reverse();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Navbar Demo"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: _animation,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                items: screens
                    .map(
                      (e) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        label: e.label,
                        icon: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: e.icon,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _setupScreens() {
    screens = [
      BottomNavBarItemData(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
        label: 'Tab 1',
      ),
      BottomNavBarItemData(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
        label: 'Tab 2',
      ),
    ];
  }
}

class BottomNavBarItemData {
  String label;
  Icon icon;

  BottomNavBarItemData({
    required this.label,
    required this.icon,
  });
}
```